# Filter array of objects to get distinct values into new array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have [created a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/hkbszL71/1/) of my question, with the help of some of the answers below.

I have an array of objects. An individual object in the a array contains:

```
obj1, obj2, obj3...
```

An example of one of the object is:

```
{
client_id: "85"
id: 1477
organisation_id: 5
task_project_id: 26
project_name: "Reiciendis adipisci fugiat."
project_description: "Soluta consequatur labore et dolores"
task_description: "Qui sunt at aut."
task_end_time: null
task_start_time: "2016-05-21 09:00:00"
transaction_id: null
}
```

I want to generate a new array of objects from this first array containing distinct entries of task_project_id. The new array should contain distinct objects structured per below:

```
{
task_project_id: 26
project_name: "Reiciendis adipisci fugiat."
}
```

I have tried `jQuery.grep`, `array.filter`, `array.map` but to no avail. I also cannot seem to find examples using "extract array of distinct objects" as search. Could someone point me to an example please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it. How does the first object example relate to the second? And how do you define a "unique" object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.map` should work just fine:

```
var b = a.map(function(e) {
  return {
    task_project_id: e.task_project_id,
    project_description: e.project_description
  }
});
```

Edit: filter out duplicates, by storing a list of already encountered "seen" task project ids:

```
var seen = {}; // keys = list of unique task project ids
var b = a.filter(function (e) {
  return seen[e.task_project_id] ? false : (seen[e.task_project_id] = true);
});
```

Putting it all together:

```
var newArray = (function (a) {
  var seen = {};
  return a.filter(function (e) {
    return seen[e.task_project_id] ? false : (seen[e.task_project_id] = true);
  }).map(function (e) {
    return {
      task_project_id: e.task_project_id,
      project_description: e.project_description
    }
  });
})(oldArray);
```

Comment: Hi @sebnukem thanks for the reply. I am looking to filter out duplicate `task_project_id` entries though.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want ? Check the output.!

```js
var oldArray = [{
    client_id: "85",
    id: 1477,
    organisation_id: 5,
    task_project_id: 26,
    project_name: "Reiciendis adipisci fugiat.",
    project_description: "Soluta consequatur labore et dolores",
    task_description: "Qui sunt at aut.",
    task_end_time: null,
    task_start_time: "2016-05-21 09:00:00",
    transaction_id: null
  }, {
    client_id: "86",
    id: 1434,
    organisation_id: 5,
    task_project_id: 22,
    project_name: "Reiciddgdgdfgci fugiat.",
    project_description: "Soluta consequatur labore et dolores",
    task_description: "Qui sunt at aut.",
    task_end_time: null,
    task_start_time: "2016-05-21 09:00:00",
    transaction_id: null
  }],
  newArray;
newArray = oldArray.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    task_project_id: obj.task_project_id,
    project_description: obj.project_description
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Hi @Nikhilesh Shivarathri close! I am seeking the new array to contain distinct task_project_id entries only. I think I can work from this now though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

ES6:

```
let map = new Map();
a = [{a:1, b:"blue"},{a:1, b:"red"}]
a.map(item=>map.set(item.a, item));
let result = [...map.values()];
```

result:

```
[ { a: 1, b: 'red' } ]
```